# GetTimeZoneInformation equivalent in ubuntu?

Tags: c++

i am using `GetTimeZoneInformation` in windows...but not able to find any equivalent in linux.
Any idea??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured it out after some more debugging time related structures.

Its better to use `struct tm * gmtime ( const time_t * timer )` which wll give the UTC time.

And can use `tzset()` and `tzname[0]` to get the timezone info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following on Unix:

```
std::string LocalTimeZone()
{
    time_t  now = time(NULL);
    struct tm tnow = *localtime(&now);
    std::string tz = tnow.tm_zone;
    std::cout << "Local timezone: " << tz << std::endl; 

    char    buff[100];
    strftime( buff, sizeof buff, "%a %b %d %Y %T %Z%z", &tnow );

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    const std::string s(buff);
    boost::split(vec, s, boost::is_any_of(" "));

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = vec.end();
    return *--i;
}
```

Which will give the current time zone as per the host machine's system settings.

Answer (score 1):

Boost has **[Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/date_time.html)**, containing a time zone database. You can use the same.